# media_handle_sideload() fails

Tags: uploads

i am used the follow script what will upload an image by URL to wp, but it fails (debugging brings "The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2016/03"). But i was wondering... the uploaded image is 778kb, upload_max_filesize in PHP-7 php.ini was 100M. On begin of week this function works fine, but since last two days (without changing anything) this will not work.

I used PHP Version 7.0.4-5 and the function loads per CLI-Script (a cronjob). The /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini upload_max_filesize was changed from 2M to 100M (also post_max_size from default to 100M). The rights on directory /tmp and /var/www/domain.tld/htdocs/wp-content/uploads are all right (chmod 0775). Both directories 2016 and 03 are chowned by www-data and have also the rights 0775.

The temporary file by download_url() exists also and are a correct jpg-file. I don't know anymore where i can look to find the error. I have test it also on a live server... the same error.

Here is the function:

```
function setThumbnail($postid,$img,$isPreview=false) {
    include_once(ABSPATH."/wp-admin/includes/media.php");
    include_once(ABSPATH."/wp-admin/includes/file.php");
    include_once(ABSPATH."/wp-admin/includes/image.php");
    global $wpdb;
    $tmp=download_url($img);
    $filename=basename($img);
    $file_arr['name']=$filename;
    $file_arr['tmp_name']=$tmp;
    if (is_wp_error($tmp)){
        @unlink($file_arr['tmp_name']);
        $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'ctcronlog',array('created'=>current_time('timestamp'),'doing'=>'download_thumb','msg'=>$tmp->get_error_message()),array('%d','%s','%s'));
        return false;
    }
    $id=media_handle_sideload($file_arr,$postid);
    if(is_wp_error($id)){
        @unlink($file_arr['tmp_name']);
        $errors=array();
        foreach($id->get_error_messages() as $err){
            $errors[]=$err;
        }
        $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'ctcronlog',array('created'=>current_time('timestamp'),'doing'=>'upload_thumb','msg'=>var_export($errors,true)),array('%d','%s','%s'));
        return false;
    }
    $src=wp_get_attachment_url($id);
    if($isPreview) {
        set_post_thumbnail($postid,$id);
    }
    return $src;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was the @copy() in wp-includes/file.php class of wordpress. This will mask the real problem why the file could not copied (the rights on on htdocs was not ok). So the problem is fixed.